# Set a browser and page title for Devise pages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have methods that set a title for the browser and for the page itself. On my Devise pages I would like to set these two methods but am not sure how to.

My Code:

**helpers/application_helper**

```
def title # for entire application
    base_title = "Testing"
  if @title.nil?
    base_title
  else
    "#{base_title} - #{@title}"
  end
end

def page_title # for page header partial
   "#{@page_title}"
end
```

**views/layouts/application**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title><%= title %></title>
      <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
      <%= favicon_link_tag %>
      <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
      <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="container">
         <%= render "shared/page_header" %>
         <%= render "shared/flash_message" %>
         <%= yield %>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

**views/shared/_page_header**

```
<% unless @page_title.blank? %>
  <div id="page-header">
    <span><%= @page_title %></span>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Now I have a RegistrationsController to override the functionality whenever I need to but as it inherits to the DeviseController, I don't think it can get to the Application Helper? I also tried to put this same code in the Registration Helper but that didn't work either. What should I do?

Comment: `DeviseController` by default extends `ApplicationController`. **[Source](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise.rb#L200)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can use;

application_helper.rb

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def title(page_title)
    content_for(:title) { page_title }
  end
end
```

application.html.erb

```
<title><%= yield :title %></title>
```

view

```
<%= title "Your page title here" %>
```

Comment: Nice, I like this even better. Thank you.

Comment: I found this only worked in the view when I used `<% content_for :title, "Your page title here" %>`. I'm using Rails 5.